# Power of Fisher test vs chi squared

Tags: chi-squared-test, statistical-power, fishers-exact-test, hypothesis-testing

Consider an $m \times n$ contingency table and test of independence.

Suppose the expected counts are such that chi-squared test is not recommended (close to zero in some cells), as it becomes pretty inaccurate.

Instead, we can run exact Fisher test.

Question 1: What are the options to compute a power of exact Fisher test? Is there a way without running expensive simulations?

Question 2 (pretty hypothetical): How bad would it be to compute a power of a chi-squared test as a proxy for power of exact Fisher test?
Computationally, it's really fast, involves effect size (closed form expression of the table entries), sample size, dofs, and alpha (p-value threshold). But is it a reasonable approximation of the true power?

Comment: The test statistic for Fisher's exact test has a hypergeometric distribution. Various implementations make different choices determining P-values for two-sided tests, so finding power will be more straightforward if you have a one-sided alternative. Of course, to find 'power' you need to have a specific alternative in mind. A complication in comparing Fisher with chi-sq is that chi-sq tests are usually two-sided. // So for a specific answer, you need to settle on a specific alternative and on a one vs. a two-sided test.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking of a two-sided both for Fisher and chi sq.

For Fisher itself I'm using implementation equivalent to fisher.test from R. 

For chi sq. the alternative would be a non-central chi sq. distribution.

Comment: There is a power and sample size procedure in R for the Fisher exact test, but not in a library I currently have installed. Google `power Fisher exact test`---and look past the ads.

Comment: @max: Is this  for $m=n=2$, where there are multiple packages or is it for general $m\times n$ tables, which is considerably more difficult?

Comment: The question is for general $m$ and $n$, my particular table is $2 \times 6$.

The R https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/statmod/versions/1.4.34/topics/power.fisher.test function seems to only support 2x2 tables. (I'm actually calling R function from python, which is already a stretch, but somehow python doesn't seem to have exact Fisher test for large tables).

Comment: The very last paragraph of http://www.biostathandbook.com/fishers.html seems to suggest that using chi sq. power analysis instead of Fisher power analysis is ok.

But I'm starting to see that the exact alternative for Fisher is kind of a crucial thing for Fisher power analysis, as @BruceET pointed out. There doesn't seem to be standard construction of alternative unlike in chi sq.

Comment: Simulation for a 2x6 table is not very expensive. I just simulated 100,000 such tables in under a second and a million tables in a few seconds on a fairly middling laptop. The harder thing is figuring out the precise alternative(s) you want to simulate.

Comment: Ok, would the following setup work? 

Suppose the alternative is constructed as follows. Take a table satisfying zero hypothesis,  e.g. with proper proportions and marginals. Generate a random matrix with all column and row sums equal to zero. Scale it to have a fixed Frobenius norm. Add it to the first table. We get a new table with the same marginal counts, but some distance away from the zero table.

Generate $N$ such tables. Run Fisher exact test for each. Compute proportion of cases when the null hypothesis was rejected. That proportion is the power. Does that sound reasonable?